# creating XML elements with PHP inside a DOM

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm trying to get this, by a reference in the google's documentation website, but the tags are not getting right, they are nesting... And what I want is to all of the tags be the children on just 1 tag, called Markers.

Here is some code to explain what I'm trying to get:

This is the result I would like to get:

```
<markers>
  <marker name="Crab Pot" address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.605961" lng="-122.340363" type="restaurant" />
  <marker name="Mama&amp;apos;s Mexican Kitchen" address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613976" lng="-122.345467" type="bar" />
  <marker name="Wingdome" address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.617214" lng="-122.326584" type="bar" />
  <marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="restaurant" />
</markers>
```

And what I'm doing is this:
    ....

```
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

But unfortunately this is the result that's is printing, where all the tags are nesting inside each other.

```
<markers>
    <marker name="Crab Pot" address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.605961" lng="-122.340363" type="restaurant">
        <marker name="Mama's Mexican Kitchen" address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613976" lng="-122.345467" type="bar">
            <marker name="Wingdome" address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.617214" lng="-122.326584" type="bar">
                <marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="restaurant">
                </marker>
            </marker>
        </marker>
    </marker>
</markers>
```

Comment: Can you check your posted code against actual code? I think you typed correctly here but mis-typed in code because as far as I see this should work without nested markers. Now if the line read: `$newnode = $node->appendChild($node);` where `$node` is being appended and not `$parnode` then I see the nested tag output.

Comment: I suggest using more meaningful variable names, not just the type. It helps to avoid mistakes. https://eval.in/431741